# Android notification icon is blank on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications, android-assets

I have been getting a blank/grey notification icon on some Android devices
(Pixel 2 XL and Pixel 5 - both Android 11), but it shows up fine on other Android
devices I tested on (Huawei P20 & P30 - both Android 10). Has anyone else come across this anomaly?

This is what I tried:

- I have ensured all icon sizes follow the [defined bitmap
  densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp) using the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default).
- I also added the the `.setColorized()` method to the
  [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setColorized(boolean)) object as it was previously missing in the
  code, but that made no difference at all. I have included my
  notification code below:

```kotlin
private fun sendNotification(title: String?, message: String?, intent: Intent) {
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0 /* Request code */,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )

    // With the default notification channel id the heads up notification wasn't displayed
    val channelId = getString(R.string.heads_up_notification_channel_id)
    val notificationBuilder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_orange))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


    if (title != null) {
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)

    }

    if (message != null) {
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message).setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(message)
        )
    }

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Test",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(Random.nextInt()/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

[image]

Comment: Here is R.mipmap.ic_stat_ic_notification a image or vector? Could you try to use only png and remove all the vector reference and see if this fixes the issue

Comment: I too face the same issue.. in my case i use "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" plugin, the notification icon is mapped to '@mipmap/ic_launcher.' Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I tested on android 9, 10, 11. It works fine.

In android studio:

- Select `image asset`
- Click `icon type`

  - Click `Notification icons`: [*looks like this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJK2u.png)
  - Or create a vector asset.

Both options worked perfectly fine for me. LMK

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling)
              sendNotification("Hello","thinking of refering friend?",intent);
        }


    private fun sendNotification(title: String?, message: String?, intent: Intent) {
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0 /* Request code */,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )

        // With the default notification channel id the heads up notification wasn't displayed
        val channelId = getString(R.string.heads_up_notification_channel_id)
        val notificationBuilder =
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abcd)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setColorized(true)
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_orange))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


        if (title != null) {
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)

        }

        if (message != null) {
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(message).setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message)
            )
        }

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    "Test",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(Random.nextInt()/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar Issue before. In my case the problem was the icon that I tried to use. I used a non-PNG file for the icon of the notification. When I switch it to PNG format, the nofication worked normally for all devices I tested.

If you are not using Png format for the icon , you can try this way.

Also, the problem can be the size of your icon in [android reference website](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder?hl=tr#setSmallIcon(int)) it is stated that

> Set the small icon to use in the notification layouts. Different classes of devices may return different sizes.

Also see [this guiadeline](https://material.io/design/iconography/product-icons.html#grid-and-keyline-shapes)  for Keyline Shapes